# HTACCESS redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

I changed the hierarchy of my site. there we 2 pages as following:

```
http://www.example.com/cms/products-search.php
```

Which moved to : /new/pro-search.php

And

```
http://www.example.com/cms/data-products-details.php?pro=1111
```

Which moved to /new/products-details.php?pro=1111

How can i handle this in htaccess and not affect SEO ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect to your new page location using

```
301 "Moved Permanently" redirect
```

Which has to be setup pro grammatically in your HTACCESS file, simple example:

```
Redirect 301 /something https://www.mynewapp.com/something/a?someextra
```

The 301 "Perma Redirect" tell Search Engine that you page has moved for good at new location and any Page Rank should be transferred to new URL.

Comment: it works for the first part but what about the second part which has dynamic parameter ?

Comment: @Ali the parameter I added was just for example, you can safety remove it. so `Redirect 301 /something https://www.mynewapp.com/something/a`